# C++ Selection Sort of an Array of String Objects

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, selection

I'm trying to implement a selection sort function for an array of user inputted string objects.  Am I on the right path as far as arguments go.  Thanks

```
void selectionSort(char ARRAY[], int size)
{
int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = ARRAY[startScan];
    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (ARRAY[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = ARRAY[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    ARRAY[minIndex] = ARRAY[startScan];
    ARRAY[startScan] = minValue;
}
}
```

Comment: String object or characters? The answer is very different in either case.

Comment: You might want to use the qsort function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: As far as arguments go? Yes, you are.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the STL libabry and declare the argument as

`std::vector< std::string >`

then the sort function will work directly, like this

```
std::vector< std::string > array;
std::sort (array.begin(), array.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *are* sorting string objects then there's a lot of problems. The code you wrote sorts *characters*. This:

```
char ARRAY[]
```

is an array of characters. These:

```
char *ARRAY[]
std::string ARRAY[]
```

are arrays of strings. You will have to change your function appropriately with either of these.

Comment: so if want to use a string array of characters am I on the right track?

Comment: @hyuj String array of characters? If you meant an "array of strings" or a 
"string array" then yes.